# Too many query in Hibernate, even lazy fetch

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

Kinda of embarrassing to ask this question after few years working with Hibernate...

I have a master_table which :

- have some @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="something ")
- and some @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
- may have some @OneToOne
- same thing in child_table

I loaded only master_table which gave me about 500 rows. However in the background, it was about 6000 queries made. (quite sure that there is no EAGER)

Question: is that normal ? Is that possible to load this table with just 1 query without impacting lazy loading mechanism, which is working quite very-well here.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite easy:
- Using Fetch = Subselect on @OneToMany gave me only one query. As it is lazy, when the children are needed, the corresponding queries will be generated
- Using BatchSize is also a good option

Comment: Or you could use the JOIN fetch mode

Comment: No, JOIN fetch mode doesn't help. There is still 1 query for Company and n queries for Employee (Tested several time). BatchSize=m help somehow because the number of queries will be 1 + n/m.

Comment: I guess it's not really clear from your question what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve. Glad you have an answer you're happy with.